# Resolution of a set, $\Delta < 0$ why?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

$$B = \left\{\frac{x}{x^2+3}, x\in \mathbb R, x\geq 0\right\}$$

Photo:
https://ibb.co/j4bDzK

The teacher already solved the exercise but i didn’t understand how he came to that solution.
In the photo at the end there are 2 points:
$$\Delta>0$$ with the two negative square roots or:
$$\Delta<=0$$

Here is what I’m asking:  Why he brought up those 2 points? Why are we considering a Delta<0 as a solution? etc.

I don’t understand how and why this is the solution.

Thanks to everyone will respond!

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos  The definition of B is not rendered correctly.  Why can I not edit it so it is correct?

Comment: @WilliamElliot What are you talking about? I did **not** reject an edition suggested made by you.

Comment: There needs to be a \ before the {. I missed this while suggesting the edit and can’t seem to do it anymore.

Comment: @William: When there is a queued edit suggestion you need to approve/reject it before you can edit something further.

Comment: I would solve it without using $D$. Let $f(x)=Mx^2-x+3M$ and consider the parabola $y=f(x)$. The vertex is $(2M,3M-\frac{1}{4M})$ with $2M\gt 0$ and $f(0)=3M\gt 0$. So, in order to have $f(x)\ge 0$ for all $x\ge 0$, it is necessary and sufficient to have $3M-\frac{1}{4M}\ge 0$, i.e. $M^2\ge\frac{1}{12}$. So, the minimum of $M$ is $\frac{1}{2\sqrt 3}$.

Comment: @mathlove Wow brilliant! How you ended up with ${frac1/(2/sqrt(3))}$ ? (You meant maximum right?)

Comment: @neilpare: $M^2\ge\frac{1}{12}$ is equivalent to $(M-\frac{1}{2\sqrt 3})(M+\frac{1}{2\sqrt 3})\ge 0$. Dividing the both sides by $M+\frac{1}{2\sqrt 3}\gt 0$ gives $M-\frac{1}{2\sqrt 3}\ge 0$. We want to have the **minimum** of $M$, not maximum. We want to have the minimum of $M$ such that $\frac{x}{x^2+3}\le M$ since such $M$ is the **maximum** of $\frac{x}{x^2+3}$.

Answer (score 1):

Your question isn’t very clear to me. From what I understand, you want to understand what a negative discriminant entails, and I’ll proceed accordingly.

Consider the case where the determinant is positive, or zero. What do these entail?

So the kind of function you derive here represents a parabola in $\mathbb{R}^2$. The points where the parabola intersects the $y$ axis are the roots. To have two distinct roots, the discriminant needs to be positive, and you have an equation of the sort $(x-\alpha)^2$ when the discriminant is exactly equal to zero. This is also when the tip of the parabola touches the axis at exactly one point.

Broadly, think of this as follows; you have a constant term in the equation, and as this increases with the other constants unchanged, the discriminant decreases. Thus, the entire graph shifts upwards with a decreasing discriminant of this nature, and when this is negative, the graph is entirely above the $y$ axis, which means that your function always takes positive values.

Comment: That is an already solved ex. made by the prof. We are studying upper and lower bound, max, min, etc. in my question I’m asking why the teacher says those two option in order to resolve the problem. The options (in the image) are that Delta > 0 with both square roots < 0 or that the Delta is <=

Comment: Or that the Delta is <= 0... I don’t know how and why he made this up? ( i sent the comment by accidenti, sorry)

Comment: So if both roots are negative, it means that the region where this is negative is some interval which is a subset of the negative results. Thus both give you that as a consequence, for $x>0$, it is positive.

Comment: I explained the importance of the discriminant being negative in my answer. Take another look.

Comment: Yeah but i know what a negative discriminant is and how it works. I asked why the teacher proceeded that way in order to find the upper bound of B. I looked the question and it is not very clear, I’m editing it... Hope you understood what i was asking now :)

Comment: From what I understand, you’re given the fact that the infimum is 0, and I’m assuming you guys haven’t done calculus yet. So I believe your professor wants to assume the existence of a maximum $M$ and then take the inequality to ensure that the infimum condition is maintained under the existence of this maximum, and see what conditions you can then impose on $M$.

Comment: ok I’m starting to understand something of what you are saying, maybe, I edited the question as good as i can, hoping it is clearer now. Anyway we have the infimum = 0 and we have to fund the maximum, the maximum is a number L >= B ( the expression in B). Now he bring the 2 possibilities with Delta <=0 and the Delta > 0 with the square roots < 0... And I don’t know why he does this (?)

Comment: The infimum being 0 implies that the function does not take negative values anywhere. Under what conditions does a quadratic equation take no negative values? Also note that as a bonus, you’re told that $x$ is only positive. Then you have the additional condition that the quadratic equation can now take negative values on some negative interval on the real line. I hope this is understandable. Read the third comment in this thread again, might be of help.

Comment: Mh ok so if i understood thee is a interval in the negative side that keeps the result positive and so satisfies the condition x>0. We have to find that interval. But once i have the Delta < 0 how can i find some results? How i calculate them?

Comment: That is what I’ve said a number of times already, I’m not sure you’re reading everything properly. A negative discriminant implies that the parabola is entirely above the axis, so it never takes negative values. Please read the entire thread properly. Everything you could possibly ask has probably been answered here.

Comment: Yeah probably but maybe in a form that is not easily comprehensible by a newbie like me. So sorry if i repeat things you already said but i think it’s an important part of the learning process and I’m here to learn. Surely not to waste your time so if you don’t want to answer me anymore feel free to do that! :) really i can understand that. Continuing my useless “speech”, the teacher also makes another strange thing: Delta = 1-12M^2 -> 1-12M^2 <= 0 -> M^2 >= 1/12, M > 0 -> “M >= 1/(2*sqrt(3)) = (sqrt(3))/6” why (in the “”)?

Comment: You are also ignoring some of my questions so try to read them agains... I repeat that I’m here to learn, if I’m doing something wrong feel free to tell me!

Comment: I do not see what else there is that you want to know but hasn't been answered. The last question you asked which I feel you haven't found a satisfactory answer to is the one about the negative discriminant and why that is of interest. To make it simpler for you, I'll pinpoint the part that is relevant: the last paragraph of my answer. If you feel that you know negative discriminants and still don't understand it, I think you need to revisit it. The only assumption in making here is that you know what a parabola is, and that you know what graphs of quadratic equations look like.